# Subclass UIImageView to store extra data on image

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am building app which allows a user to drag UIImageView's. If two UIImageView's are dragged to the same 'segment' the first one dragged there needs to be returned to it's starting position. I will be creating the UIImageView's programatically on demand.

Should I subclass UIImageView to create a way to store the UIImageView's original starting position so I can return it to it's starting position when needed or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a subclass is a good way to go.

Something like this should do the job:

```
@interface ImageViewWithStartPosition : UIImageView

@property (nonatomic) CGPoint startPosition;

- (void)returnToStartPosition;

@end
```

You could also create a category and [add a property to it using the runtime](http://www.davidhamrick.com/2012/02/12/Adding-Properties-to-an-Objective-C-Category.html), but I'd recommend against it if subclassing is an option.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to keep this kind of information in `UIViewController` for example, solution could be `NSMutableDictionary` of starting coordinations.

You can save starting `CGPoint` encapsulated into `NSValue` with key created from image view's hash.

Something like this:

```
//  Save origin of image view to NSMutableDictionary with key created from UIImageView's hash
CGPoint point = imageView.frame.origin;
[mutableDictionary setObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:point] forKey:@([imageView hash])];


//  Retrieve previous coordinations of image view from NSMutableDictionary by UIImageView's hash
NSValue *originalCoordsValue = [mutableDictionary objectForKey:@([imageView hash])];

if(originalCoordsValue) {
    //  I have previous origin of the image view
    CGPoint originalPoint = [originalCoordsValue CGPointValue];
    //  Do whatever you want with previous coordinations
    NSLog(@"Original point: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(originalPoint));
}
```

The best solution is often a matter of opinion, so Im not saying this is the best one. Decide yourself :-)